# Macbook Pro 2.2ghz 2011 (OSX 10.6.7) problem with NTFS 3G

Tags: ntfs-3g

I installed NTFS 3G but now get the following error message when I try to plug in my external drive. I also get it on startup about my Windows partition.

Uninstall/ reinstall does not work.

> NTFS-3G could not mount
>   /dev/disk1s1at /volumes/freeagent
>   GoFlex Drive because the following
>   error occured:
>
> /library/filesystems/fuse.fs/support/fusefs.kext
>   failed to load- (libkern/kext) link
>   error; check the system/ kernel logs
>   for errors or try kextutil(8). The
>   MacFUSE file system is not available
>   (71)

Any help would be great. I'd hope to avoid reinstalling OS X if possible!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I went into system preferences and uninstalled NTFS-3G and then uninstalled [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). I can now see and access the external drive again but read only mode.

> MacFUSE allows you to extend Mac OS
>   X's native file handling capabilities
>   via 3rd-party file systems. It is used
>   as a software building block by dozens
>   of products.